# Request an Ajax form through Ajax [solved]

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I want to load a form through Ajax in a custom Javascript Event as it is explained in [this tutorial](https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/trigger-drupal-managed-ajax-calls-any-time-drupal-7). I receive the form, but its ajaxified behaviour is very strange.

My Javascript:

```
var address = $(location).attr('protocol') + '//' + $(location).attr('hostname');
var url_get_button = address + 'mymodule/get_button/';

Drupal.ajax.prototype.specifiedResponse = function() {
  var ajax = this;
  try {
    $.ajax(ajax.options);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
};

var ajax_settings = {};
ajax_settings.event = 'onload';
ajax_settings.keypress = false;
ajax_settings.prevent = false;
ajax_settings.url = url_get_button;
Drupal.ajax['get_button'] = new Drupal.ajax(
  null, $(document.body), ajax_settings);

//the following is somewhere at the right js event...
Drupal.ajax['get_button'].specifiedResponse();
```

My php code:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/get_button'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_send_button',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  );
  $items['mymodule/next_ajax'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_next',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
  );
}

function mymodule_get_form ($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'click',
      'path' => 'mymodule/next_ajax/',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
  return $form;  
}

function mymodule_send_button() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_get_form');
  $form = ajax_pre_render_element($form);

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#replace-this', render($form));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "some_js");

  $button = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($button);
}

function mymodule_next() {
  commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_alert('works!');
  $message = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($message);
}

function mymodule_node_view() {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');
}
```

Well, if `Drupal.ajax['get_button'].specifiedResponse();`is called in the Javascript event, the button will be loaded, but if I click on the button, the page is reloaded with `url_get_button` (which was used to request the button) instead of getting the alert window with 'works!'.

But if I add another form builder function and call this function with `drupal_get_form()` within the hook_node_view() (without returning anything!!), it will work.

So I add:

```
function mymodule_get_another_form ($form, &$form_state) {
  //I have to add the following line in order that it works
  $form2['submit'] = array();
  return $form2;
}
```

and change my hook_node_view() to:

```
function mymodule_node_view() {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');
  $form2 = drupal_get_form('mymodule_get_another_form');
  //I don't return $form2...
}
```

Well, in summary: I want to request an ajaxified button through a custom Javascript event. I receive the button, but it is not ajaxified and on top the wrong url is linked. But if i call `drupal_get_form()` with another 'empty' form builder function during the page load, it will work and I will get the alert message after clicking on the button.

I use Drupal 7.

Does anyone have an advice for me? Why isn't it working without the second form builder function and why does it work with it?

I would welcome every advice.
Thank's a lot.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it: In a sidebar, there was another form with a submit button provided by another module. This submit button has also the key 'submit'. In the form builder function I changed the key 'submit' to e.g. 'mymodule_submit' and now it works! So I don't need this strange second form builder function anymore.

Comment: @Wtower well, OP need to wait for 48 hours (I guess) to accept their own answer. ;)